# Leaflet map grey on mobile browsers

Tags: javascript, leaflet

This leaflet map is working fine on desktop browsers, it is not on mobile browsers, don't understand where is the error!

```
var map = new L.Map("tour-map",{ zoomControl: false, maxZoom: 15 });

var basemaps = {
    opentopomap: L.tileLayer('http://{s}.tile.opentopomap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png'),
    hikebike: L.tileLayer('http://{s}.tiles.wmflabs.org/hikebike/{z}/{x}/{y}.png'),
    worldimagery: L.tileLayer('http://server.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/rest/services/World_Imagery/MapServer/tile/{z}/{y}/{x}')
};

L.control.layers(basemaps).addTo(map);

basemaps.opentopomap.addTo(map);
```

Chrome console doesn't show any errors...

This is the css:

`#tour-map { position: relative; margin: 0 auto; width: 100%; height: 360px; }`

Comment: Welcome to SO! How do you define your `"tour-map"` map container size? Is it mobile browser or WebView?

Comment: Hello ghybs and thanks for your help!

This is the css:


`#tour-map {
 position: relative;
 margin: 0 auto;
 width: 100%;
 height: 360px;
}`

Comment: You should _edit_ your question instead of adding more info in comments (there should be a grey link below your question). Is it mobile browser or WebView?

Comment: Sorry ghybs it it my first time on Stack Overflow and I'm not very familiar with this editor. By the way the problem is related to mobile browsers (like I wrote on the first post)

Comment: Np, everybody learns at some point… :-) Unable to reproduce your issue with the provided code (once you `map.setView(latlng, zoom)`) on Chrome on Android: https://jsfiddle.net/3v7hd2vx/2103/embedded

Comment: Can I post the URL of the website?

Comment: You could, but it is much more preferable that you set up an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which code you share in your question, and possibly on a live code collaborating service (like the above JSFiddle). Very few people will have the courage to go to your website and dig into your full code, and this is not the spirit of SO (i.e. gathering knowledge for future readers, hence we cannot solely rely on external resources that will surely change).

Comment: I tried to follow your example and replicate the whole code on https://jsfiddle.net/3v7hd2vx/2151/

Comment: Thank you for the JSFiddle. Note that raw.githubusercontent is not suitable as CDN, you should use rawgit instead, like you did for the GPX lib. Furthermore do not mix HTTP and HTTPS protocols: when you access the JSFiddle through HTTPS, some of your HTTP resources will not load (like your GPX file). Please share a replication example that works basically (in particular add the `setView`), except for the issue you describe. Finally the point of the MCVE is that you do not share your full code, but you strip it from secondary features, and show only what is necessary to make the issue occur.

Comment: BTW you seem not to use your browser [console](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Web_Console) (the link is for Firefox, but all browsers have something similar). Learn how to use it to see error messages.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help, I followed your hints and used rawgit:
https://jsfiddle.net/3v7hd2vx/2181/
it is still not working but anyway you pointed me to solve the problem on the live website: mixing HTTP and HTTPS was the cuplrit!

Comment: Good job! :-) Feel free to [write your own answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) and to accept it later on, so that if other people have the same issue as yours they can find a solution quicker!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was caused by mixing HTTP and HTTPS protocols.
Thanks a lot to ghybs for helping me!